# How to print a guint64 value when using glib?

Tags: c, glib

**Problem**

I am making use of the GLib 2.0 library, and declared a gunit64 variable. I wish to print its value to screen, but its not working properly.

**Code**

Consider the following code snippet as an example. I declare a guint64 variable, and try to print its value.

```
guint64 myValue = 24324823479324;
printf("My Value: %d\n", myValue);
```

**Warning**

I get this warning:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘guint64’
```

**Output**

I get a strange negative number on screen:

> My Value: -1871285220

**Further Comments**

I tried to search the API's documentation, and I found the following under guint64:

> An unsigned integer guaranteed to be 64 bits on all platforms. Values
>   of this type can range from 0 to G_MAXUINT64 (=
>   18,446,744,073,709,551,615).
>
> To print or scan values of this type, use G_GINT64_MODIFIER and/or
>   G_GUINT64_FORMAT.

Therefore, I assume I have to use either the modifier or format definitions. However, the documentation does not show how to use them. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've found the proper [macro for this](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Basic-Types.html#G-GUINT64-FORMAT:CAPS). Here's how to use it:

```
printf("My value: %" G_GUINT64_FORMAT "\n", myValue);
```

Note that the macro is a quoted string literal, so the above is the proper syntax. Also note that the `%` is not part of the macro.

Your number appears negative since you're using `%d`, which expects an `int`, and the bits of your number, when viewed as a smaller, signed `int`, encode something negative.

Comment: @Goaler444 Maybe stdout just isn't getting flushed due to missing newline? Try `printf("My value: %" G_GUINT64_FORMAT "\n", myValue);` instead.

Comment: @Goaler444 It would be interesting to learn exactly how your code looks, there might be something silly (like a missing newline as Ancurio says). This really should work, and is the right way to do it.

Comment: @Ancurio, I think it was a flushing problem. I added the "\n" and it works.

Comment: @unwind Thank you, it works now. Sorry I didnt give you the correct answer. It did not work for me initially. My bad.